# Toolbar problems when scroll disabled

Tags: android, css, angular, firefox

I have a situation where disabling scroll on mobile when my cart is turned on causes really weird graphical issue with android firefox toolbar. Cart is a fixed container taking an entire screen.

When toolbar is shown it just stays there and freezes (probably because i just turned off scrolling) but when its hidden and I'll turn on my cart white bar shows up in place of the toolbar [picture related](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlyTH.png), as you can see it's obscuring my buttons as well. I found workaround for that where I make custom --vh unit based on actual screen height.

```
let vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01;
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`);
```

I disable scroll by ading this on body

```
 overflow-y:hidden;
```

I was also trying to disable it with different tricks like setting position to fixed or relative but it causes the same bug.

This only happens on firefox android.

Is there a way I can turn off scrolling without causing this, or maybe someone knows how to fix displaying 100vh height on mobile with pure css?

Comment: try `min-height: -webkit-fill-available;` instead `height: 100vh`

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have mention that I already tried -webkit-fill-available before and dosn't help, actually quite the opposite, turns off my overflow in cart completely. I think it's supposed to help with safari not firefox.